# uploading videos though asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, video, delegates

I have to upload video on a server though my application. So, i want to create application in such way that it can upload multipe videos at a time.

So, for that i can create separate **threads** like below code:

```
     Thread childThread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(UploadVideo));
     childThread1.Start(videos[videocount++]);
```

this method is working fine and uploads multiple files **simultaneously**.

But i am able to do multiple files upload simultaneously though delegates also.

```
UploadVideoDelegate delUploadVideo;  
AsyncCallback objAsyncCallBack = new AsyncCallback(this.TocuhLogResult);  
IAsyncResult objIAsyncRes;  
delUploadVideo = new UploadVideoDelegate(UploadVideo);  
objIAsyncRes = delInsertTouchLogToDB.BeginInvoke(videos[videocount++],  objAsyncCallBack, null);
```

So, which one i should use here and why ?

Comment: As per Sagar solution at here, you have to use delegates, because in my 4 years of experience, I had faced so many problem with thread, we have to always keep in my that, we should never use thread until we need id... Here you be able to use delegate than you should prefer delegate. and +1 for your good question.

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to use **delegate** because sometimes when multiple thread come than there may be a crash of some thread, as my personal opinion the better way is to use it by delegates instead of threading.

In further more its all of to you.